# how to add variable to addMonths() in apex

Tags: apex, trigger

I am working on one trigger where I need to update a datatime field from custom metadata type.

foR EXAMPLE, if Lead.Implied_Consent_Source__c matches with metadata.MasterLabel then I need to fetch a number field from metadata which I am able to get.

Once I get that number then I need to update a datetime field on lead,

Lead.Implied_Consent_Expiry__c = system.now().addMonths(I need to pass number field which I got from Metadata) but when I did that then I am getting error that variable does not exists.

My code is below.

```
for(Lead lead1: leads){
        if(metadatamap.containskey(lead1.Implied_Consent_Source__c))
            decimal var = metadatamap.get(lead1.Implied_Consent_Source__c).Consent_Period__c;
            lead1.Implied_Consent_Expiry__c = system.now().addMonths(var);
    }
```

I am getting error that variable does not exist: var

Can anyone helps me out in this issue please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put {} for the inner IF. Try below code.

```
for(Lead lead1: leads){
        if(metadatamap.containskey(lead1.Implied_Consent_Source__c)){
                decimal var = metadatamap.get(lead1.Implied_Consent_Source__c).Consent_Period__c;
                lead1.Implied_Consent_Expiry__c = system.now().addMonths(var);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Yep, this is why it's recommended to _always_ use brackets around if/else/while/for/etc... If you don't, then the only statement that's "inside" the if/else/etc... is the _very next line_ (or maybe it's the next _statement_, that research would be something that could improve this answer) which can make things hard(er) to debug.